# Outlook 2016 - Sorting restricted items by received date/ sent on and pick the latest email

Tags: vba, outlook

Using Outlook 2016, I tried to find the latest email sent to or received from specific email address and save its copy to specific folder.

I have developed some code but I think I have problem with sorting and picking the correct restricted items. Once they sorted by date, the code doesn't pick the latest email. It consistently return the same email if run the code several times but definitely it doesn't return the latest email.

Below is the function I created. Hope somebody is able to help.
Thanks in advance.

```
Sub Get_The_Emails(intTarget As Integer)
    Dim oInboxFolder As Outlook.folder, oSentFolder As Outlook.folder
    Dim tFolder As Outlook.folder, sFolder As Outlook.folder
    Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim oInboxItems As Outlook.Items, oSentItems As Outlook.Items, colItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim oFilteredInboxItems As Outlook.Items, oFilteredSentItems As Outlook.Items, oFilteredItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim oReceivedItem As Outlook.MailItem, oSentItem As Outlook.MailItem, oItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim strSentFilter As String, strReceivedFilter As String
    Dim intFolder As Integer, intMode As Integer, intSource As Integer
    Dim theReceivedTime As Date, theSentTime As Date
    Dim inputFile As String
    Dim inputNum As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim strEnviro As String, strContent As String
    Dim varList As Variant


    strEnviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
    inputFile = strEnviro & "\Desktop\Email-List.txt"

    If Dir(inputFile, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MsgBox "File: " & inputFile & " could not be found", vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        CleanList inputFile
        DoEvents
    End If

    inputNum = FreeFile
    Open inputFile For Input As inputNum
        strContent = Input(LOF(inputNum), inputNum)
    Close inputNum

    If Len(strContent) < 6 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid email address list", vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        varList = Split(strContent, vbNewLine)
    End If

    Set oNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oInboxFolder = oNS.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set oInboxItems = oInboxFolder.Items
    Set oSentFolder = oNS.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    Set oSentItems = oSentFolder.Items


    intFolder = intTarget
    Select Case intFolder
        Case 1: strFolder = "1. Latest"
        Case 2: strFolder = "2. Received"
        Case 3: strFolder = "3. Sent"
    End Select

    On Error Resume Next
    Set tFolder = oNS.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders(strFolder)
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Set tFolder = oNS.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders.Add(strFolder)
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    intMode = intTarget
    Select Case intFolder
        Case 1: For i = LBound(varList) To UBound(varList)
                    strSentFilter = "@SQL=" & "urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto" & _
                                " Like '%" & CStr(varList(i)) & "%' Or " & _
                                "urn:schemas:httpmail:displaycc" & _
                                " Like '%" & CStr(varList(i)) & "%' Or " & _
                                "urn:schemas:httpmail:displaybcc" & _
                                " Like '%" & CStr(varList(i)) & "%'"

                    Set oFilteredInboxItems = oInboxItems.Restrict("[SenderEmailAddress] = '" & CStr(varList(i)) & "'")
                    With oFilteredInboxItems
                        If .Count > 0 Then
                            oFilteredInboxItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
                            theReceivedTime = oFilteredInboxItems(1).ReceivedTime
                        End If
                    End With

                    'Set oFilteredSentItems = oSentItems.Restrict("[To] = '" & CStr(varList(i)) & "'")
                    Set oFilteredSentItems = oSentItems.Restrict(strSentFilter)
                    With oFilteredSentItems
                        If .Count > 0 Then
                            oFilteredSentItems.Sort "[SentOn]", True
                            theSentTime = oFilteredSentItems(1).SentOn
                        End If
                    End With

                    If oFilteredInboxItems.Count > 0 And oFilteredSentItems.Count = 0 Then
                        Set oItem = oFilteredInboxItems(1)
                    End If

                    If oFilteredInboxItems.Count = 0 And oFilteredSentItems.Count > 0 Then
                        Set oItem = oFilteredSentItems(1)
                    End If

                    If oFilteredInboxItems.Count > 0 And oFilteredSentItems.Count > 0 Then
                        If theReceivedTime > theSentTime Then
                            Set oItem = oFilteredInboxItems(1)
                        Else
                            Set oItem = oFilteredSentItems(1)
                        End If
                    End If

                    oItem.Copy
                    oItem.Move tFolder
                    Debug.Print oFilteredInboxItems(1).Subject, theReceivedTime, oFilteredSentItems(1).Subject, theSentTime

                    Set oFilteredInboxItems = Nothing: Set oFilteredSentItems = Nothing: Set oFilteredItems = Nothing
                    Set oReceivedItem = Nothing: Set oSentItem = Nothing: Set oItem = Nothing
                Next

        Case 2: For i = LBound(varList) To UBound(varList)
                    Set oFilteredInboxItems = oInboxItems.Restrict("[SenderEmailAddress] = '" & CStr(varList(i)) & "'")
                    With oFilteredInboxItems
                        If .Count > 0 Then
                            oFilteredInboxItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
                            theReceivedTime = oFilteredInboxItems(1).ReceivedTime
                            Set oReceivedItem = oFilteredInboxItems(1).Copy
                            oReceivedItem.Move tFolder
                            Debug.Print CStr(varList(i)), oReceivedItem.Subject, theReceivedTime
                        End If
                    End With

                    Set oFilteredInboxItems = Nothing: Set oFilteredSentItems = Nothing: Set oFilteredItems = Nothing
                    Set oReceivedItem = Nothing: Set oSentItem = Nothing: Set oItem = Nothing
                Next

        Case 3: For i = LBound(varList) To UBound(varList)
                    strSentFilter = "@SQL=" & "urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto" & _
                                " Like '%" & CStr(varList(i)) & "%' Or " & _
                                "urn:schemas:httpmail:displaycc" & _
                                " Like '%" & CStr(varList(i)) & "%' Or " & _
                                "urn:schemas:httpmail:displaybcc" & _
                                " Like '%" & CStr(varList(i)) & "%'"

                    'Set oFilteredSentItems = oSentItems.Restrict("[To] = '" & CStr(varList(i)) & "'")
                    Set oFilteredSentItems = oSentItems.Restrict(strSentFilter)
                    With oFilteredSentItems
                        Debug.Print i, CStr(varList(i)), .Count
                        If .Count > 0 Then
                            oFilteredSentItems.Sort "[SentOn]", True
                            theSentTime = oFilteredSentItems(1).SentOn
                            Set oSentItem = oFilteredSentItems(1).Copy
                            oSentItem.Move tFolder
                            Debug.Print i, CStr(varList(i)), oSentItem.Subject, theSentTime
                        End If
                    End With

                    Set oFilteredInboxItems = Nothing: Set oFilteredSentItems = Nothing: Set oFilteredItems = Nothing
                    Set oReceivedItem = Nothing: Set oSentItem = Nothing: Set oItem = Nothing
                Next
    End Select
End Sub
```

**EDITED 20 APR 2020**

Further to Dmitry's advice,
I modified the code as below but it seems it does NOT work well on the Sent Items. I have 2 issues, hope somebody could help.

1. It does not catch the newest/ latest email. I suspect it has something to do with the filter used to find the recipient's email address. Could somebody help to improve the filter so that it can look for the recipient's email address in all To, CC, and BCC fields?
2. If I have a long list of the email address to be found, it missed/ it skipped some email addresses (it seems the Find function does not return any result for some email addresses). The target emails are there but the code fail to pull the corresponding email.

Below is the modified code:

```
Sub Get_The_Emails(intTarget As Integer)
    Dim oInboxFolder As Outlook.folder, oSentFolder As Outlook.folder
    Dim tFolder As Outlook.folder, sFolder As Outlook.folder
    Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim oInboxItems As Outlook.Items, oSentItems As Outlook.Items, colItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim oFilteredInboxItems As Outlook.Items, oFilteredSentItems As Outlook.Items, oFilteredItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim oReceivedItem As Outlook.MailItem, oSentItem As Outlook.MailItem, oItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim strSentFilter As String, strReceivedFilter As String
    Dim intFolder As Integer, intMode As Integer, intSource As Integer
    Dim theReceivedTime As Date, theSentTime As Date
    Dim inputFile As String
    Dim inputNum As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim strEnviro As String, strContent As String
    Dim varList As Variant

    strEnviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
    inputFile = strEnviro & "\Desktop\Email-List.txt"

    If Dir(inputFile, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MsgBox "File: " & inputFile & " could not be found", vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        CleanList inputFile
        DoEvents
    End If

    inputNum = FreeFile
    Open inputFile For Input As inputNum
        strContent = Input(LOF(inputNum), inputNum)
    Close inputNum

    If Len(strContent) < 6 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid email address list", vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        varList = Split(strContent, vbNewLine)
    End If

    Set oNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oInboxFolder = oNS.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set oInboxItems = oInboxFolder.Items
    Set oSentFolder = oNS.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    Set oSentItems = oSentFolder.Items

    intFolder = intTarget
    Select Case intFolder
        Case 1: strFolder = "1. Latest"
        Case 2: strFolder = "2. Received"
        Case 3: strFolder = "3. Sent"
    End Select

    On Error Resume Next
    Set tFolder = oNS.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders(strFolder)
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Set tFolder = oNS.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders.Add(strFolder)
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    intMode = intTarget
    Select Case intFolder
        Case 1
                For i = LBound(varList) To UBound(varList)
                    strSentFilter = "@SQL=" & "urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto" & _
                                " Like '%" & CStr(varList(i)) & "%' Or " & _
                                "urn:schemas:httpmail:displaycc" & _
                                " Like '%" & CStr(varList(i)) & "%' Or " & _
                                "urn:schemas:httpmail:displaybcc" & _
                                " Like '%" & CStr(varList(i)) & "%'"

                    oInboxItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
                    Set oReceivedItem = oInboxItems.Find("[SenderEmailAddress] = '" & CStr(varList(i)) & "'")
                    If Not oReceivedItem Is Nothing Then
                        theReceivedTime = oReceivedItem.ReceivedTime
                    End If

                    oSentItems.Sort "[SentOn]", True
                    Set oSentItem = oSentItems.Find(strSentFilter)
                    If Not oSentItem Is Nothing Then
                        theSentTime = oSentItem.SentOn
                    End If

                    If Not oReceivedItem Is Nothing And oSentItem Is Nothing Then
                        Set oItem = oReceivedItem
                    End If

                    If oReceivedItem Is Nothing And Not oSentItem Is Nothing Then
                        Set oItem = oSentItem
                    End If

                    If Not oReceivedItem Is Nothing And Not oSentItem Is Nothing Then
                        If theReceivedTime > theSentTime Then
                            Set oItem = oReceivedItem
                        Else
                            Set oItem = oSentItem
                        End If
                    End If

                    oItem.Copy
                    oItem.Move tFolder
                    If Not oReceivedItem Is Nothing And Not oSentItem Is Nothing Then
                        Debug.Print "*** 1. Latest from/to: " & CStr(varList(i)) & " ***"
                        Debug.Print , "Received:" & vbTab, oReceivedItem.Subject, theReceivedTime
                        Debug.Print , "Sent:" & vbTab, oSentItem.Subject, theSentTime
                        Debug.Print "=================================================="
                    End If

                    Set oReceivedItem = Nothing: Set oSentItem = Nothing: Set oItem = Nothing
                Next

        Case 2
                For i = LBound(varList) To UBound(varList)
                    oInboxItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
                    Set oReceivedItem = oInboxItems.Find("[SenderEmailAddress] = '" & CStr(varList(i)) & "'")
                    If Not oReceivedItem Is Nothing Then
                        theReceivedTime = oReceivedItem.ReceivedTime
                        oReceivedItem.Copy
                        oReceivedItem.Move tFolder
                        Debug.Print "*** 2. Received from: " & CStr(varList(i)) & " ***"
                        Debug.Print , oReceivedItem.Subject, theReceivedTime
                        Debug.Print "================================================="
                    End If

                    Set oReceivedItem = Nothing: Set oSentItem = Nothing: Set oItem = Nothing
                Next

        Case 3
                For i = LBound(varList) To UBound(varList)
                    strSentFilter = "@SQL=" & "urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto" & _
                                " Like '%" & CStr(varList(i)) & "%' Or " & _
                                "urn:schemas:httpmail:displaycc" & _
                                " Like '%" & CStr(varList(i)) & "%' Or " & _
                                "urn:schemas:httpmail:displaybcc" & _
                                " Like '%" & CStr(varList(i)) & "%'"

                    oSentItems.Sort "[SentOn]", True
                    Set oSentItem = oSentItems.Find(strSentFilter)
                    If Not oSentItem Is Nothing Then
                        theSentTime = oSentItem.SentOn
                        oSentItem.Copy
                        oSentItem.Move tFolder
                        Debug.Print "*** 3. Sent to: " & CStr(varList(i)) & " ***"
                        Debug.Print , oSentItem.Subject, theSentTime
                        Debug.Print "==========================================="
                    End If

                    Set oReceivedItem = Nothing: Set oSentItem = Nothing: Set oItem = Nothing
                Next
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no reason to use `Restrict` since you only want one item from the returned collection. Sort the items collection first (`Items.Sort`), then use `Items.Find` to find the match.

Comment: Hi @Dmitry Streblechenko,
I have edited the code as suggested and can see the code works on the Inbox folder.
But I still have 2 issues I lined up in the edited post.

Comment: A filter on To/CC/BCC won't work - these properties contain display names only, not addresses. MAPI lets you search on recipients, but OOM does not expose it. If using Redemption is an option, it lets you specify Recipients in the search queries, and searching on To/CC/BCC actually searches in the recipient table, not just PR_DISPLAY_TO / CC / BCC properties.

Comment: Unfortunately, Redemption is not an option for me. Is it the only way?

Comment: Or Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only).

Comment: Hi @Dmitry,
That's also a hard choice for now. Anyway, Thanks for your help.
I will go to another direction, I will retrieve the associated Display Name for the supplied email address and use it to filter the Sent Items.
But I don't know how to retrieve the associated Display Name of an email address, probably you could help? I post the question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61340561/outlook-vba-function-to-retrieve-display-name-of-an-email-address

Comment: Try to call Namespace.CreateRecipient / Recipient.Resolve, then read Recipient.Name property. Note that it is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the changeover to the new filter "strSentFilter" was incomplete.

After replacing the old filters this appears to "find the latest email sent to or received from specific email address and save its copy to specific folder."

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Get_The_Emails_TEST()

    ' 1. Latest
    ' 2. Received
    ' 3. Sent

    Get_The_Emails 1

End Sub


Sub Get_The_Emails(intTarget As Long)

    Dim oInboxFolder As Folder, oSentFolder As Folder
    Dim tFolder As Folder, sFolder As Folder

    Dim oInboxItems As items, oSentItems As items
    Dim oFilteredInboxItems As items, oFilteredSentItems As items

    Dim oReceivedItem As MailItem, oSentItem As MailItem, oItem As MailItem

    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim strSentFilter As String, strReceivedFilter As String

    Dim intFolder As Long, intMode As Long, intSource As Long
    Dim theReceivedTime As Date, theSentTime As Date

    Dim inputNum As Long, i As Long
    Dim strEnviro As String, strContent As String

    'Dim varList As Variant
    Dim varList() As Variant

    ' for testing without "Email-List.txt"
    varList() = Array("address1@somewhere.com", "address2@somewhere.com", "noAddress@nowhere.com")

    'strEnviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
    'inputFile = strEnviro & "\Desktop\Email-List.txt"

    'If dir(inputFile, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    '    MsgBox "File: " & inputFile & " could not be found", vbCritical, "Error"
    '    Exit Sub
    'Else
    '    CleanList inputFile
    '    DoEvents
    'End If

    'inputNum = FreeFile
    'Open inputFile For Input As inputNum
    '    strContent = Input(LOF(inputNum), inputNum)
    'Close inputNum

    'If Len(strContent) < 6 Then
    '    MsgBox "Invalid email address list", vbCritical, "Error"
    '    Exit Sub
    'Else
    '    varList = Split(strContent, vbNewLine)
    'End If

    Set oInboxFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set oInboxItems = oInboxFolder.items

    Set oSentFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    Set oSentItems = oSentFolder.items

    intFolder = intTarget
    Select Case intFolder
        Case 1: strFolder = "1. Latest"
        Case 2: strFolder = "2. Received"
        Case 3: strFolder = "3. Sent"
    End Select

    On Error Resume Next
    Set tFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.folders(strFolder)
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Set tFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.folders.Add(strFolder)
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    intMode = intTarget
    Select Case intFolder

        Case 1: For i = LBound(varList) To UBound(varList)

                    Debug.Print
                    Debug.Print i, CStr(varList(i))

                    strSentFilter = "@SQL=" & "urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto" & _
                                " Like '%" & CStr(varList(i)) & "%' Or " & _
                                "urn:schemas:httpmail:displaycc" & _
                                " Like '%" & CStr(varList(i)) & "%' Or " & _
                                "urn:schemas:httpmail:displaybcc" & _
                                " Like '%" & CStr(varList(i)) & "%'"

                    'Set oFilteredInboxItems = oInboxItems.Restrict("[SenderEmailAddress] = '" & CStr(varList(i)) & "'")
                    Set oFilteredInboxItems = oInboxItems.Restrict(strSentFilter)

                    With oFilteredInboxItems
                        If .count > 0 Then
                            oFilteredInboxItems.sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
                            theReceivedTime = oFilteredInboxItems(1).ReceivedTime

                            Debug.Print "Inbox:"
                            Debug.Print theReceivedTime & " " & oFilteredInboxItems(1).Subject
                        End If
                    End With

                    'Set oFilteredSentItems = oSentItems.Restrict("[To] = '" & CStr(varList(i)) & "'")
                    Set oFilteredSentItems = oSentItems.Restrict(strSentFilter)

                    With oFilteredSentItems
                        If .count > 0 Then
                            oFilteredSentItems.sort "[SentOn]", True
                            theSentTime = oFilteredSentItems(1).SentOn

                            Debug.Print "Sent folder:"
                            Debug.Print theSentTime & " " & oFilteredSentItems(1).Subject
                        End If
                    End With

                    If oFilteredInboxItems.count > 0 And oFilteredSentItems.count = 0 Then
                        Set oItem = oFilteredInboxItems(1)
                        Debug.Print "Inbox:"
                    End If

                    If oFilteredInboxItems.count = 0 And oFilteredSentItems.count > 0 Then
                        Set oItem = oFilteredSentItems(1)
                        Debug.Print "Sent folder:"
                    End If

                    If oFilteredInboxItems.count > 0 And oFilteredSentItems.count > 0 Then
                        If theReceivedTime > theSentTime Then
                            Set oItem = oFilteredInboxItems(1)
                            Debug.Print "Inbox item chosen:"
                        Else
                            Set oItem = oFilteredSentItems(1)
                            Debug.Print "Sent folder item chosen:"
                        End If
                    End If

                    If Not oItem Is Nothing Then
                        oItem.Copy
                        oItem.Move tFolder
                        Debug.Print oItem.Subject
                    Else
                        Debug.Print "No item found."
                    End If

                    Set oFilteredInboxItems = Nothing: Set oFilteredSentItems = Nothing
                    Set oReceivedItem = Nothing: Set oSentItem = Nothing: Set oItem = Nothing
                Next

        Case 2: For i = LBound(varList) To UBound(varList)

                    Debug.Print
                    Debug.Print i, CStr(varList(i))

                    strSentFilter = "@SQL=" & "urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto" & _
                                " Like '%" & CStr(varList(i)) & "%' Or " & _
                                "urn:schemas:httpmail:displaycc" & _
                                " Like '%" & CStr(varList(i)) & "%' Or " & _
                                "urn:schemas:httpmail:displaybcc" & _
                                " Like '%" & CStr(varList(i)) & "%'"

                    'Set oFilteredInboxItems = oInboxItems.Restrict("[SenderEmailAddress] = '" & CStr(varList(i)) & "'")
                    Set oFilteredInboxItems = oInboxItems.Restrict(strSentFilter)

                    With oFilteredInboxItems
                        If .count > 0 Then
                            oFilteredInboxItems.sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
                            theReceivedTime = oFilteredInboxItems(1).ReceivedTime
                            Set oReceivedItem = oFilteredInboxItems(1).Copy
                            oReceivedItem.Move tFolder

                            Debug.Print "Inbox:"
                            Debug.Print theReceivedTime & " " & oFilteredInboxItems(1).Subject
                        Else
                            Debug.Print "No item found."
                        End If
                    End With

                    Set oFilteredInboxItems = Nothing: Set oFilteredSentItems = Nothing
                    Set oReceivedItem = Nothing: Set oSentItem = Nothing: Set oItem = Nothing
                Next

        Case 3: For i = LBound(varList) To UBound(varList)

                    Debug.Print
                    Debug.Print i, CStr(varList(i))

                    strSentFilter = "@SQL=" & "urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto" & _
                                " Like '%" & CStr(varList(i)) & "%' Or " & _
                                "urn:schemas:httpmail:displaycc" & _
                                " Like '%" & CStr(varList(i)) & "%' Or " & _
                                "urn:schemas:httpmail:displaybcc" & _
                                " Like '%" & CStr(varList(i)) & "%'"

                    'Set oFilteredSentItems = oSentItems.Restrict("[To] = '" & CStr(varList(i)) & "'")
                    Set oFilteredSentItems = oSentItems.Restrict(strSentFilter)

                    With oFilteredSentItems

                        If .count > 0 Then
                            oFilteredSentItems.sort "[SentOn]", True
                            theSentTime = oFilteredSentItems(1).SentOn
                            Set oSentItem = oFilteredSentItems(1).Copy
                            oSentItem.Move tFolder

                            Debug.Print "Sent folder:"
                            Debug.Print theSentTime & " " & oFilteredSentItems(1).Subject
                        Else
                            Debug.Print "No item found."
                        End If
                    End With

                    Set oFilteredInboxItems = Nothing: Set oFilteredSentItems = Nothing
                    Set oReceivedItem = Nothing: Set oSentItem = Nothing: Set oItem = Nothing
                Next
    End Select
End Sub
```