# Outlook VBA - Function to retrieve Display Name of an email address

Tags: vba, outlook

Apologize as I come up without any code, I just simply don't know how to start.

So let say I have an email address. I want to check whether this email address belongs to any contact in any contact folder or in any address book of my Outlook. If yes, I want to retrieve the associate Display Name of the email address. I need the function fast enough to check long list of email addresses.

Hope somebody can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `Namespace.CreateRecipient` / `Recipient.Resolve`, then read `Recipient.Name` property. Note that it is not unique.

If you need to resolve multiple entries, create a temporary message, add the values to the `MailItem.Recipients` collection, call `Recipients.ResolveAll`.

Comment: I use the below code but it does not work as expected.
`Sub ResolveName()
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 ' VIVI PPIC <asst_ppic2@guardian.co.id>
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("asst_ppic2@guardian.co.id")
 myRecipient.Resolve
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then
    Debug.Print myRecipient.Name
 End If
End Sub`

I want to retrieve "VIVI PPIC" but it returns "asst_ppic2@guardian.co.id"
In my contact, I set the contact's full name: VIVI PPIC and display as: VIVI PPIC.

Comment: Yes, it does return True

Comment: Does Recipient.AddressEntry.GetContact return a valid ContactItem object?

Comment: Yes, it does.
Thank you @Dmitry